# Возврат нескольких файлов

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi

Каким образом можно вернуть несколько файлов в ответ на запрос к handler? Нашёл [вариант](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61163024/return-multiple-files-from-fastapi) через архивирование. Но выглядит костылём.

Comment: Это зарядка для ума или киллер-фича какого-то своего проекта?:) И почему же костылем? В корне не согласен, выглядит вполне разумно. Так почта, например, делает, когда одним запросом скачиваешь все вложения.

Comment: @mrEvgenX костыль, поскольку необходимо прибегать к дополнительному слою логики в виде архивации. Хотелось бы нативной реализации. Как я выяснил, http нативно не умеет

Comment: Раз уж шашкой махать, тогда не костыль, а middleware... Основную мысль и смысл вопроса я понял.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем случае, ответ таков. `http` не поддерживает в ответе несколько файлов. Для этого используется чаще всего архивирование. Другим способом является запрос конкретного файла. Например, по его `id` или `name`. Но такой способ подходит, если эти имена известны заранее. В противном случае, выхода нет.